# Why is it returning NaN instead of 7?

Tags: javascript

```js
var sum = 2;

function addFive() {
  var sum = sum + 5;
  console.log(sum); //why not 7
}
addFive();
```

Why is it returning `NaN` instead of 7?

Comment: Because you are declared a local variable `sum` inside the function. Remove `var` before `var sum = sum+5;`

Comment: The newly declared variable `sum` inside the function is shadowing the outer `sum`. You only need `var` when you introduce a new variable.

Comment: try `sum = sum+5;` without the `var` so that you are not declaring a new variable by the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make things clearer, your code is essentially being read like so:

```js
var sum = 2;

function addFive() {
  var sum; // implicitly equal to undefined
  sum = sum + 5; // sum = undefined + 5 = NaN
  console.log(sum); // NaN
}
addFive();
```

As you can see, you're redeclaring `sum` and it is set to `undefined`. So, when you try and add `2` to `undefined` you're going to get `NaN` (Not a Number).

Instead, you can reference your outer `sum` variable by not redefining it within your function and instead just reassign its value:

```js
var sum = 2;

function addFive() {
  sum = sum + 5; // sum = 2 + 5 = 7
  console.log(sum); // 7
}
addFive();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the variable `sum` again in the function. This has all to do with scoping in JavaScript.

Take a look at the following [article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) to learn more.

In this case, the local variable (the one that's declared inside the function) gets priority by the JavaScript parser. This behavior's called 'shadowing'. It starts at the innermost scope being executed at the time, and continues until the first match is found, no matter whether there are other variables with the same name in the outer levels or not.

Comment: var sum = 2;
function addFive (){
console.log(sum);
}
addFive ();

This returns 2.. I don't understand.. why can't I declare the variable again as a local scope ?

Comment: @SubhamBisoyi `why can't I declare the variable again as a local scope ?`,  you can and you have, and that's why your answer is 2.   Otherwise what you want is global scope.

Comment: @SubhamBisoyi Or, you can even declare a local variable, but you'll have to use a different name for it, to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Because you are declared a local variable sum inside the function.
You have to use `this`.

```js
var sum = 2;

function addFive(){
  var sum = this.sum + 5;
  console.log(sum);
}

addFive();
```

In this context, `this` will refer to the global object (in a browser, `window`), so the above code is equal to:

```js
var sum = 2;

function addFive(){
  var sum = window.sum + 5;
  console.log(sum);
}

addFive();
```

You can read more about `this` [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/8376184) or [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Using `this` here is confusing and in strict mode will fail.

Comment: now I get it.Thanks a lot. How can I mark this question as answered ?

Comment: Let's hope you never want to start using modern js modules, or `use strict;` as you might have a fair bit of code to repair.. :)

Comment: Would be frustrating to use `window.sum` in nodejs

Comment: @Mark You might want to look into `globalThis` for that very reason.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis